# Copying AFHTTPRequestOperation results in error "request body stream exhausted"

Tags: ios, afnetworking

### Problem

My app lets users upload photos.  This works great.

Now, I am trying to implement a "retry" function if the photo upload fails, for example due to a slow connection.

Here's my retry code:

```
self.operation = [self.operation copy];  // Creates a new operation with the same NSURLRequest

[self.operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    // do success stuff

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog("%@", error);

}];

[[MyAFHTTPClient sharedClient] enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:self.operation];
```

Upon starting, the failure block is called, outputting:

```
$0 = 0x12636b50 Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1021 "request body stream exhausted" UserInfo=0x12637810 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://my/long/url/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://my/long/url/, NSLocalizedDescription=request body stream exhausted, NSUnderlyingError=0x13046bb0 "request body stream exhausted"}
```

### Question

How do I change my code to restart the image upload correctly?

### What I've tried

I think the issue is that `operation.request.HTTPBodyStream` is an `NSInputStream`, which cannot be restarted.

The method `-[AFURLConnectionOperation connection:needNewBodyStream:]` appears to provide a copy of the input stream.  I set a breakpoint in there; it's not called when copying or starting the operation, and I'm not sure how to trigger it.

There's some discussion on a [similar issue on the AFNetworking GitHub page](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/661), but that relates to retrying after authentication failure.

### Other info

My URL Request object is created using `-[AFHTTPClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:
                          path:
                    parameters:
     constructingBodyWithBlock:]`

Comment: Why not call the same method that tried the upload at first?

Comment: At this point the view is closed, text boxes deallocated, image compressed appropriately, etc.  I suppose I could keep all that stuff around and rebuild a new operation from scratch.  The docs say "the copying mechanism returns a completely new instance, which can be useful for retrying operations" - so it seems like I should be able to just copy the operation and retry.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this :

```
-(void)uploadImage:(NSData *)imageData retry:(BOOL)retry
{
    AFHTTPClient *myClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseUrl:myBaseURL];
    NSURLRequest *request = [myClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"                                                                                                    
                                                                path:myPath
                                                          parameters:myParametersDictionary
                                           constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData> formData){
                                               [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData 
                                                                           name:myImageName 
                                                                       fileName:myFileName 
                                                                       mimeType:@"image/jpg"];
                              }];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [myClient HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                                                                // do success stuff
                                                                                  }
                                                                          failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                                                               NSLog("%@", error);
                                                                               if (retry) {
                                                                                   [self uploadImage:imageData
                                                                                               retry:NO];
                                                                               }
                                           }];
    [myClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
}
```

Of course the first time you would call it with `retry:YES`

Comment: Something like this could work, but my question is about AFHTTPClient's documented support for copying an AFHTTPRequestOperation object to retry it.  +1 for a usable workaround, though.